# Multiple Text Cursor

Tags: keyboard, macos

I recieved new mbp with el capitan

when i type on my macbooks retina display i see multiple phantom cursors

when I type in any application, mostly those with a white background the cursor persists. if i move using the arrow keys, the text rerenders removing the extra cursors.

[image: phantom text cursor]

what is interesting about this issue, is that if I move the application to one of my dell monitors, i do not see the additional cursors but this laptop is fairly new and the display is otherwise fine so it is unclear whether this is software are hardware related.

- I am not using any bluetooth devices.
- I have also tried a PRAM reset.
- An upgrade to latest el capitan did not correct the issue
- sometimes linebreaks cause the cursors to appear, sometimes going back in the text with the arrow keys does as well
- sometimes using the arrow keys causes the phantom cursors to intermittently disappear
- the issue occurs on my macs retina display but not on a lower quality dell monitor

i have checked system preferences but nothing stands out

Comment: Does this occur both with the Dell monitor attached and detached?

Comment: @agentroadkill yes